# Configuring SSL on Apache HTTPd installed on VMWare VM : bad certificate

Tags: centos, vmware, ssl, https, httpd

I am building a Reverse Proxy server with **Apache HTTPd 2.4.6**, under **CentOS 7** (freshly installed) running on a **VMWare VM**.

I also followed recommandations of https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI (found through post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14830133/apache-httpd-virtual-host-ssl-certificate).
And post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36050140/centos-httpd-ssl-404-error.

- **Apache HTTPd actual configuration (/etc/httpd/conf.d/my.domain.com.conf) :**

  ```
  LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

  Listen 443

  NameVirtualHost *:443
  SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off

  <VirtualHost *:443>

  ServerName my.domain.com

  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RCA+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/my.domain.com.cer
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/my.domain.com.key
  SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/chained.pem

  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <LocationMatch "/myapp">
      ProxyPass http://X.X.X.X:8080/app
      ProxyPassReverse http://X.X.X.X:8080/app
  </LocationMatch>
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

The Certificat Chain File `chained.pem` contains my CA.

This CA is the issuer of the certificate `my.domain.com.cer` and the private key stored in `my.domain.com.key` are correct.

This CA has been added to `/etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt`

The syntax is correct (`httpd -t`).

**> Problem : when I hit my.domain.com, the VMWare certificate is sent instead of mine...**

- **From a client, when I do a request to my domain with curl :**

  ```
  curl -v https://my.domain.com -k

  (...) 
  * Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
  * successfully set certificate verify locations:
  *   CAfile: C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
    CApath: none
  * TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
  (...)
  * Server certificate:
  *  subject: C=US; L=Palo Alto; OU=VMware; CN=VMware;     emailAddress=none@vmware.com
  *  start date: May 24 09:24:16 2017 GMT
  *  expire date: May 24 09:24:16 2018 GMT
  *  issuer: C=US; L=Palo Alto; OU=VMware; CN=VMware; emailAddress=none@vmware.com
  *  SSL certificate verify result: self signed certificate (18), continuing anyway.
  ```
- **From a client, when I do a request to my domain with Chrome :**

On the HTTPd server, nothing about SSL errors in httpd debug logs ... :

```
[Wed Mar 14 05:31:00.572506 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 2715] AH02200: Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server 'my.domain.com:443'
[Wed Mar 14 05:31:00.573282 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 2715] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(506): AH02249: unencrypted RSA private key - pass phrase not required
[Wed Mar 14 05:31:00.573333 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 2715] AH01914: Configuring server my.domain.com:443 for SSL protocol
[Wed Mar 14 05:31:00.574085 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 2715] ssl_engine_init.c(872): AH01904: Configuring server certificate chain (2 CA certificates)
[Wed Mar 14 05:31:00.574105 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 2715] ssl_engine_init.c(406): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
[Wed Mar 14 05:31:00.574116 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 2715] ssl_engine_init.c(919): AH02232: Configuring RSA server certificate
[Wed Mar 14 05:31:00.574356 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 2715] ssl_util_ssl.c(489): AH02412: [my.domain.com:443] Cert matches for name 'my.domain.com' [subject: emailAddress=xxxx@yyy.fr,CN=my.domain.com ....... / notbefore: Mar 12 14:58:57 2018 GMT / notafter: Mar  9 14:58:57 2028 GMT]
[Wed Mar 14 05:31:00.574369 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 2715] ssl_engine_init.c(974): AH02236: Configuring RSA server private key
[Wed Mar 14 05:31:00.640615 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 2715] AH02200: Loading certificate & private key of SSL-aware server 'my.domain.com:443'
[Wed Mar 14 05:31:00.641115 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 2715] ssl_engine_pphrase.c(506): AH02249: unencrypted RSA private key - pass phrase not required
[Wed Mar 14 05:31:00.641180 2018] [ssl:info] [pid 2715] AH01914: Configuring server my.domain.com:443 for SSL protocol
[Wed Mar 14 05:31:00.641646 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 2715] ssl_engine_init.c(872): AH01904: Configuring server certificate chain (2 CA certificates)
[Wed Mar 14 05:31:00.641656 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 2715] ssl_engine_init.c(406): AH01893: Configuring TLS extension handling
[Wed Mar 14 05:31:00.641666 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 2715] ssl_engine_init.c(919): AH02232: Configuring RSA server certificate
[Wed Mar 14 05:31:00.642392 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 2715] ssl_util_ssl.c(489): AH02412: [my.domain.com:443] Cert matches for name 'my.domain.com' [[subject: emailAddress=xxxx@yyy.fr,CN=my.domain.com ....... / notbefore: Mar 12 14:58:57 2018 GMT / notafter: Mar  9 14:58:57 2028 GMT]
[Wed Mar 14 05:31:00.642492 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 2715] ssl_engine_init.c(974): AH02236: Configuring RSA server private key
[Wed Mar 14 05:31:00.656912 2018] [proxy:debug] [pid 2717] proxy_util.c(1843): AH00925: initializing worker http://X.X.X.X:8080/app shared
[Wed Mar 14 05:31:00.656964 2018] [proxy:debug] [pid 2717] proxy_util.c(1885): AH00927: initializing worker http://X.X.X.X:8080/app local
[Wed Mar 14 05:31:00.656984 2018] [proxy:debug] [pid 2717] proxy_util.c(1936): AH00931: initialized single connection worker in child 2717 for (X.X.X.X)
```

No /etc/httpd/logs/ssl_error log.

I do not understand why my clients receives the WMWare certificate instead of mine... Any idea ? :(

*Notes : there is not iptables service installed & the default file /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf is not loaded (renamed to ssl.conf.bak)*

Answer (score 1):

OK. Found. After long days of headaches.

- If you are not using a bridged connection, the domain `my.domain.com` has to be bound to the VM IP, not the Host IP. Check it in your domain controller.
- Edit the file `config.xml` (Windows default path : `C:\ProgramData\VMware\hostd\config.xml`) to delete the block:

  `<!-- Remove the following node to disable SSL -->
  <ssl>
  <!-- The server private key file -->
  <privateKey>C:\ProgramData\VMware\ssl/rui.key</privateKey>
  <!-- The server side certificate file -->
  <certificate>C:\ProgramData\VMware\ssl/rui.crt</certificate>-->
  <!-- The SSL version to use -->
  <!-- <sslVersion>all</sslVersion> -->
  </ssl>`

The certificates managed by the VM will be shown first.
You can also change the `rui.crt` and `rui.key` but they will be applied to all VMs. It is not that I want.

- VMWare has to be stopped, and the WMWare Workstation Service needs to be restarted (command lines: `net stop VMwareHostd` then `net start VMwareHostd`)
- Re-run the VM. Done!